# how to append string in global variable of string in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have created global string in app delegate class and append strings in that string in multiple classes as my application control moves but i m getting only last appended string.

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *strConacatResponse;
```

in appdelegate.m

```
self.strConacatResponse = [self.strConacatResponse stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name : %@ ",name]];
```

then in another classes

```
NSString *strDates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n Common utilities not expire *** EndDate: %@ *** StartDate: %@ ",paramEndDate,paramStartDate];


    [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse =  [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse stringByAppendingString:strDates];
```

in my 3rd class

```
 NSString *strTemp = @" \n Database getSuscriptionStatus error in api calling of apple   ";
    [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse stringByAppendingString:strTemp];
```

but getting only last string

Comment: Can you show sharedAppDelegate method?

Comment: What do you mean by last string? Could please tell what exact string you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the self.strConacatResponse First in you appDelegate and Use an NSMutableString while declaring the variable.

First step would be (IN appDelegate) :-

```
self.strConacatResponse=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name : %@ ",name];
```

Then append the strings as usual

Answer (score 1):

Declare the property variable as NSMutableString

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableString *strConacatResponse;
```

in appdelegate.m

```
self.strConacatResponse=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
self.strConacatResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name : %@ ",name];
```

then in second classes

```
NSString *strDates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n Common utilities not expire *** EndDate: %@ *** StartDate: %@ ",paramEndDate,paramStartDate];

 [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse,strDates ];
```

in Third class

```
NSString *strTemp = @" \n Database getSuscriptionStatus error in api calling of apple   ";


[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ",[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].strConacatResponse,strTemp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string needs to be mutable to be able to append new strings:

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableString *strConacatResponse;
```

Then (for instance) in `AppDelegate`:

```
strConacatResponse = [NSMutableString new];
```

And now you can add more strings to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point existing logging APIs, because it seems that you're trying to achieve some sort of logging: [os_log](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc), NSLog, [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack).
Those are battle-proven APIs, so depending on your needs it might be a better option to not reinvent the wheel.